# Integrate clojure spec

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

This question might be very basic, but I am new to clojure and could not figure out how to proceed with this.

**abc.clj** :

```
(ns abc) 
(defn foo 
  [i] 
  (+ i 20))
```

I am writing clojure spec for this function in another file **abc_test.clj**.

```
(ns abc_test
  (:require [clojure.spec :as s]
            [clojure.spec.test :as stest]
            [clojure.test :refer [deftest is run-tests]]
            [abc :refer [foo]]
            ))

(s/fdef foo
        :args (s/cat :i string?)
        :ret string?
        :fn #(> (:ret %) (-> % :args :i)))

(deftest test_foo
  (is (empty? (stest/check `foo))))

(run-tests)
```

This test works absolutely fine (test should fail) if I put the function (foo) in abc_test namespace but if I require it (like above), then the test gives incorrect result.

Not sure what is going wrong here. Any heads up shall be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `s/fdef`, the symbol name needs to resolve to a fully-qualified symbol. The way you have it, `foo` is resolving to `abc_test/foo`. You want it to refer to foo in the other namespace:

```
(s/fdef abc/foo
        :args (s/cat :i string?)
        :ret string?
        :fn #(> (:ret %) (-> % :args :i)))
```

Or another trick is to leverage syntax quote (which will resolve symbols inside it given the current namespace mappings):

```
(s/fdef `foo
        :args (s/cat :i string?)
        :ret string?
        :fn #(> (:ret %) (-> % :args :i)))
```